# How to find and change part of html in IE6 by javascript

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I have webpage and I need to make some changes in this page. I am using IE6 in compatibility mode:

The part of html I need to change seems like this:

```
<SPAN title="Klepnutím otevřete" 
      class=attachment url="/Activities/Attachment/download.aspx" 
      userId="{4618A8F6-8B8F-E611-940B-005056834715}" 
      merchantId="{74F4AC81-FB14-DC11-BF2E-00145ED73B3E}" 
      attachmentType="5" 
      attachmentId="{1828327C-74A6-E611-940B-005056834715}">
   <IMG border=0 
        src="/_forms/attachments/16_generic.gif" 
        align=absMiddle>&nbsp;Account.xml
</SPAN>
```

I would like to change the url to something else by javascript.

Is there some way how to do it? I know, that there are some fuctions like getelementbyId, but I can not use it, as this element does not have the ID. Also it seems, that I can not use xpath, as it is not supported in IE6.

Thanks for all replies!

Comment: Is this element on a website you are visiting or one that you are creating?

Comment: May help: `getElementsByClassName` polyfill for IE6

Comment: Your `img` tag doesn't have an `>` at the end of it.

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` is supported in IE6. You would likely need to use this and loop over the result, checking each element checking classname or using `getAttribute` to check other attributes to find the right one. Without knowing what makes this element unique when compared to the rest of the page, all I can do is make a suggestion like this.

Comment: Damn, are people still supporting IE but even worse IE6?

Comment: Are you trying to select `<SPAN>` or `<IMG>`?

Comment: Why are you using IE6? Many sites have given up on IE8 these days, IE6 is prehistoric.

Comment: Hello yes, I am trying to rewrite something in Microsoft CRM 3 :) And have to use IE6..

Comment: Do you have the option to load jQuery? The older versions have IE6 support.

Answer (score 0):

You said you're getting this: `Object doesn't support property or method 'getElementsByClassName'`

That means the `document` doesn't have that method on it. Here's a good polyfill for that method in older IEs:

```
function getElementsByClassName(node, classname) {
    var a = [];
    var re = new RegExp('(^| )'+classname+'( |$)');
    var els = node.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for(var i=0,j=els.length; i<j; i++)
        if(re.test(els[i].className))a.push(els[i]);
    return a;
}
```

Once that function is declared, you can use it. Just remember that it's not a method on the `document` like it would be in older browsers.

```
var spans = var tabs = getElementsByClassName(document.body,'span');

for(var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
  var title = spans[i].getAttribute('title');

     if(title === "Klepnutím otevřete") {
        spans[i].setAttribute('url', 'this/is/your/custom/url.aspx')
     }
}
```

Here, I used the `title` attribute to try and find the right `span`. I have no idea if this title is unique to just this `span` element, so you might need to validate that and select it differently if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `getElementsByTagName`

```js
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');

for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
  
  // find an element with a certain class
  if (spans[i].getAttribute('class') == 'attachment') {
    
    // set new value
    spans[i].setAttribute('url', 'some other url');
    
  }
}
```

```html
<SPAN title="Klepnutím otevřete" 
      class="attachment"
      url="/Activities/Attachment/download.aspx" 
      userId="{4618A8F6-8B8F-E611-940B-005056834715}" 
      merchantId="{74F4AC81-FB14-DC11-BF2E-00145ED73B3E}" 
      attachmentType="5" 
      attachmentId="{1828327C-74A6-E611-940B-005056834715}">
   <IMG border=0 
        src="/_forms/attachments/16_generic.gif" 
        align="absMiddle"/>&nbsp;Account.xml
</SPAN>
```